# Adjectives order

Tags: word-usage, usage

I have come across different Adjectives Order Lists on the internet. A web page of Bristol University says as follows: Number - Opinion - Size - Age - Shape - Color - Nationality/Origin - Material-Purpose.

According to that order : *"I have a nice small old round brown Chinese Wooden serving bowl"* is a correct sentence. Is that order correct?

I'ts a quite awkward list, I know. It's just for the sake of checking the order. Also, should there be any commas between the adjectives, or just between adjectives that are interchangeable?

Comment: None of those "adjective order" rules are universally true - they all just reflect attempts to identify relatively common *tendencies* in natural speech. Realistically, no-one would ever say anything like your "bowl" example, so it's completely meaningless to ask whether it's "correct" or not. Effectively, it's closer to "gibberish" than "correct English"

Comment: ...you might be interested in [If you have more than one adjective to describe a noun, is there is a specific order you put them?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120510/) (which this question might be a duplicate of), but note that no-one has even bothered to upvote the only answer there.

Comment: I see. I guess you're right since I have found many other responses like yours on grammar pages.

Comment: You may also be interested in this question on ELU, which addresses whether adjective order can affect literal meaning:   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/can-changing-the-order-of-adjectives-alter-the-literal-meaning-of-a-phrase

Answer (score 1):

The list, although open to interpretation, is a good guideline if you're not sure.     Using it will help prevent miscommunication.  There is an upper limit to chained adjectives.  Not a 'hard' limit but a comprehension limit. By the time I get to "Chinese, wooden" in your list, "nice, small, and old" have been forgotten.