# Adjectives order in my sentence

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Adjectives order is a bit confusing and tricky to me. What order would be appropriate to say :

> Naked bony girls in magazines.

Or

> Bony naked girls in magazines.

If I refer to [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120510/if-you-have-more-than-one-adjective-to-describe-a-noun-is-there-is-a-specific-o) I'd be tempted to say the second sentence is more accurate, "naked" being the condition (I guess...) and "bony" being the shape. What do you think ?

Comment: I see no particular preference for the adjective sequence here. [Nor do writers in general.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bony+naked%2Cnaked+bony&year_start=1840&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbony%20naked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnaked%20bony%3B%2Cc0) Don't think of that "Royal order of Adjectives" as being a true "grammatical rule" - it's just a ***rule of thumb*** (that often turns out to be "accurate / predictive", but isn't necessarily even *relevant*).

Comment: Your choice really depends on whether you're thinking in terms of ***naked girls** [who are bony]* or ***bony girls** [who are naked]*. In the context of the contextually-relevant type of magazines, that probably reflects which of those two characteristics the writer is most "outraged" by (is he bothered about "nudie" magazines in general, or *specifically* bothered about the more recent tendency for them to feature emaciated / androgynous women?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Thanks for your comments, that would be more **naked girls** _[who are bony]_ . As for what bothers the most, I'd say both sides you mentionned matter equally.

Comment: Well, you might wish to note that [***naked girls** in magazines*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22naked+girls+in+magazines%22) is a more "familiar" concept than [***bony girls** in magazines*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bony+girls+in+magazines%22) (there are *no written instances* of the latter, so the best Google Books can do is redirect me back to your actual question here). It's usually more natural to tack another modifying adjective before a "known" collocation, rather than breaking that collocation up with an "inserted" adjective.